# In c++, how to free memory of few elements in a vector and still have the same indexing for other elements

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I actually want to index the elements in a vector by the value it stores so that it is easy to retrieve them rather than searching for. So I do not want the vector to change its length nor the rest of the elements to change their indices. Can this be achieved in vectors or are there any other datastructures I can use?

Comment: Is it a vector of pointer? Free it and set it to `std::nullptr`.

Comment: See `std::map` or `std::set`

Comment: You can use an associative table like ``std::map`` ? The key would be the element that you want to store.

Comment: `std::map`, `std::set`, their `unordered_` counterparts, also `std::list` will not invalidate iterators when you erase something from it

Comment: "I actually want to index the elements in a vector by the value it stores" I am a bit confused about that first sentence. If the index is the same as the value stored in the vector, then you dont need the vector...

Answer (score 4):

> In c++, how to ***free memory of few elements*** in a vector and still have
>   the same indexing for other elements

No, you can't. C++ mandates [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to lay its elements in a contiguous memory. There is no way you can free memory for elements "in-between".

You can use [`std::unordered_map<int, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). That way, you still have the same indexes while you can free other indexes. However, the performance of `std::unordered_map` may differ from `std::vector` because they are completely different data structures.

You should however use [`std::unordered_map::find(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) to obtain the index rather than it's [`operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) so that you do not re-insert a default element, should the index not exist.